# How to create a Logic/Script for a Data Extension?

Tags: ampscript

I always implement scripts into a Cloudpage or directly into a newsletter but I never created a script which will run by her own in a special interval. Would that be possible? Maybe every night?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [script activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/server_side_javascript_activity/) that is available that allows you to do that. However, it's for Server-Side JavaScript opposed to AMPscript. Once you save the script in the script activity you can then add it to an automation just like any other activity and execute it at the required intervals.

The feature isn't typically on by default so you will likely need to request it to be enabled by support. You should then see it listed as an option with the other activities.